# apply patch in spark installation

Tags: git, apache-spark, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

We have a problem with our hortonworks installation, specifically with our spark version 1.6.

We have a streaming spark app which one fail with this error:

https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10621

I know, obviously is resolved and if I download the most recent version of spark 1.6 I resolve the problem, but in my case I have the Hortonworks 2.5 version and I can not delete my current instalation and donwnload the new installation, actually I dont know if I can delete my current instalation of hortonworks and re-install again with the last version of spark because I think if do that I reinstall the same version with the same bug.

Anyway in the github repository they explain I should apply the patch of github, but here is my question.

How can I apply this patch in my installation and recompile all spark installation? some how to or step to step..............

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the cluster owned by hortonworks i will suggest to connect  with their team to apply the patch

Comment: Probably will be the best solution but in our case we have lost the technical support  and We need to it manually. Thanks

Comment: then stop the existing service and start from the fresh rather than applying patch to the existing spark .. it is doable please check this .. https://www.dezyre.com/apache-spark-tutorial/apache-spark-installation-tutorial